# Why is Firebase reporting wrong Screen data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I have an application with 3 view controllers inside a pagingViewController.

I also have a logEvent tracking 4 different things such as author title, video duration, etc.

The Problem is that on firebase it is showing the wrong firebase_screen_class. It is not reporting the right screen I am on.

Also on the dashboard under user engagement it is showing me the WRONG screens as where the user is most engaged ( beta iOS app that has not luahced).

Please take a look at the picture!

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The automatic screen reporter may try to be smart to guess your view controller but since your view contains multiple view controllers, it may not guess correctly. You can turn this feature off and log the screen manually to be more accurate:

```
[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClass];
```

To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag **FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled** to **NO** in the **Info.plist**

More information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews)